# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column one to many(inverse) relation laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I have two models `Tour.php` and `TourCategory.php`:

`Tour.php`

```
protected $table = `tours`;

public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TourCategory');
}
```

`TourCategory.php`

```
protected $table = 'tcategories';

public function tours()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tour');
}
```

My db tables are as follows:

`tours` table

`id|title|category_id|content|`

`tcatgegories` table

`id|name`

And I have a view to show the all tours belonging to a category with the following code:

```
    @foreach ($category->tours as $tour)
     <tr>
        <th>{{ $tour->id}}</th>
        <td>{{ $tour->title}}</td>
        <td>
            <span class="label label-default">{{$category->name}}</span>
        </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

With this above code I'm getting error of:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tours.tour_category_id' in
'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tours` where `tours`.`tour_category_id` = 1 and 
`tours`.`tour_category_id` is not null) (View: F:\multiauth_tutorial-master\resources\
views\admin\categories\show.blade.php
```

I have used same code for my previous projects also but didn't had any errors. Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with `_id`. However, if the foreign key on the model is not `*_id`, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the `belongsTo` method

So, you need to [specify a foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse):

```
public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TourCategory', 'category_id');
}
```

> You may also override the foreign and local keys by passing additional arguments to the `hasMany` method.

```
public function tours()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tour', 'category_id');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Or use `tour_category_id` instead of `category_id` in the tours table.

Comment: Added `category_id ` as foreign key and the error is still the same.

Comment: @TanjaForsberg your original question is about inverse one to many relationship (which is `belongsTo()`). If you're using `tours()` relationship, you also need to add a custom foreign key name to the `hasMany()` relationship. You can see an example in updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable guidance. I'll always keep your suggestions in mind.

Answer (score 1):

in Tour.php

```
 /**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function tours()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tour::class, 'category_id');
}
```

in TourCategory.php

```
/**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TourCategory::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this column `tour_category_id` lis not found in your `tours` table, change your sql query to

```
select * from `tours` where `tours`.`category_id` = 1 and `tours`.`category_id` is not null
```

Comment: I know but I have and had in the past `category_id` field in `tours `. App is looking for column that don't exists.